# Fluent Validation : String Contain Another String

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, fluentvalidation

i'm trying to see if AzureAdRegister.Scopes Contains The AzureAd.ClientId by something like the spaghetti code below.
and it's crashing once the validation of the model launched, i think this validation rule is not correct, but i was able to make that check without fluent validation for now;
is it because of ToSting() or what? thanks in advance :)

```
//for more clarity
public class AzureAd
{
    public string Instance { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }
    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }
    public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
    public string CallbackPath { get; set; }
    public List<string> Scopes { get; set; }
    public List<string> DefaultScopes { get; set; }
    public string ClientSecret { get; set; }
    public List<string> ClientCertificates { get; set; }
}

public class AzureAdRegister
{
    public string AuthorizationUrl { get; set; }
    public string TokenUrl { get; set; }
    public string Scopes { get; set; }
    public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
}

public class AzureConfiguration
{
    public AzureAd AzureAd { get; set; }
    public AzureAdRegister AzureAdRegister { get; set;}
}


// there is the issue
public class AzureConfigurationValidator : AbstractValidator<AzureConfiguration>
{
    public AzureConfigurationValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(azure => azure.AzureAdRegister.Scopes)
            .Must((azure,scope) => scope.Contains(azure.AzureAd.ClientId.ToString()))
            .WithMessage("the scope of registeration app must contains the client id of the main app");
        
    }
}
```

Comment: "and it's crashing once the validation of the model launched" what error do you get?

Comment: exception type: System.NullReferenceException...
message: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"...
source: FluentValidation... @gunr2171

Comment: Which line throws that exception, and which object is null?

Comment: once the request goes through the app.MapControllers() in the pipeline sir @gunr2171

Comment: You're going to need to show us the exact details of the AzureConfiguration instance you're validating. Does it have all properties populated, including AzureAd and the ClientId of AzureAd? How do you know they're populated?